# Check value and return boolean value in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was watching video about creating game in unity and I saw a weird statement and tried it in my IDE, but I get error - I guess the statement about check variable if empty or not.

This is the statement:

```
public bool empty => tile == null;
```

And this is the error I get:

> Unexpected symbol `=>', expecting` ,', `;', or` ='

I need an explanation, feel free to edit the question to help any reader and thank you already

Video link :
https://youtu.be/4NFZwPhqeRs?t=1917

Comment: Is the language C# or UnityScript (you've tagged both languages).

Comment: but isn't UnityScript use C# language ?

Comment: No. From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html) - _"UnityScript, a language designed specifically for use with Unity and modelled after JavaScript;"_

Comment: @AbdelbassetBelaid check the description of `unityscript` tag

Comment: So you can use C# or `UnityScript` to write Unity code, but they are different languages.

Comment: but what is the main difference between them? @GuruStron

Comment: As for C# this code (after fixing `puplic` -> `public`) would be a valid [expression-bodied read-only property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

Comment: @AbdelbassetBelaid the main difference would be that they are completely different languages with completely different syntax, one of which I don't know much about) I would guess that when creating a unity script you can select language which would be used for the script, so select C# and the code should be fine.

Comment: This expression is valid in `C#`, you are probably trying to write `C#` code in a `UnityScript` IDE

Comment: Is the version of C# (not .NET) older than C# 6.0? Lambda bodied get-only properties were introduced with C# 6.0. Before that you'd write it as `public bool empty { get { return tile == null; } }`. This feels unlikely though, so I wonder if Lior is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code line you have shown declares a property. It uses the [C# expression-bodied syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) as a shortcut for:

```cs
public bool empty {
    get { 
        return tile == null;
    }
}
```

It was introduced with [C# version 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-60).

You have to write this at the class level. It does not work in a method. But then you can access this property in a method:

```cs
public MyTestClass
{
    private string title = "test";

    public bool Empty => tile == null;

    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Empty);
    }
}
```

Note that I am using `PascalCase` for the property. `camelCase` is used only for fields, local variables and parameters.

The `String` class has a handy static method for testing whether a string is `null` or an empty string `""`. You might use this instead to make it more robust:

```cs
public bool Empty => String.IsNullOrEmpty(tile);
```